# wordpress contactform7 textarea cols and rows change in smaller screens

Tags: html, wordpress, contact-form-7

I used contactform7 to create the contact form for a wordpress site. I want to reduce the rows in a textarea on that form for smaller screen sizes. Is there any method I can use using contactform7's own syntax? If not what are my options?

Below is the syntax for textarea in contactform7 btw.

```
 [textarea* your-message 40x7]
```

(40 - cols, 7 - rows)

Comment: I don't think tha's possible trough the backend. The easyest way would be to set the height with CSS an set some breakpoints.

Comment: that was my first idea. but I want to avoid the scroll bar. thanks.

Comment: I used this jQuery Plugin. It adjusts the height of the textarea whenever you have a line-break: http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/

Answer (score 135):

Even though this question is more than 5yrs old, it is still active regularly, and like me many of us trying to get a clear answer to this question.

You can also type `10x` for cols and `x2` for rows if you want to have only one attribute.

```
[textarea* your-message x3 class:form-control] <!-- only rows -->
[textarea* your-message 10x class:form-control] <!-- only columns -->
[textarea* your-message 10x3 class:form-control] <!-- both -->
```

Comment: If there are CSS rules already applied, those won't be working. I recommend using CSS if you are not sure whether your content is styled using CSS or not.

Answer (score 27):

In the documentaion http://contactform7.com/text-fields/#textarea

`[textarea* message id:contact-message 10x2 placeholder "Your Message"]`

The above will generate a textarea with cols="10" and rows="2"

```
<textarea name="message" cols="10" rows="2" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-textarea wpcf7-validates-as-required" id="contact-message" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's not in the current documentation. Do you think I can disable cols and rows all together?

Comment: It works thank you, but I am interested to know why this is not in the documentation. 2 years since your comment and I can't find it in the docs anywhere. You might consider updating your link because there is nothing there.

Answer (score 9):

Code will be As below.

```
[textarea id:message 0x0 class:custom-class "Insert text here"]<!-- No Rows No columns -->

[textarea id:message x2 class:custom-class "Insert text here"]<!-- Only Rows -->

[textarea id:message 12x class:custom-class "Insert text here"]<!-- Only Columns -->

[textarea id:message 10x2 class:custom-class "Insert text here"]<!-- Both Rows and Columns -->
```

For Details: https://contactform7.com/text-fields/

Comment: This same answer was already posted 3 years before this one. Did you even read through the other answers?

Answer (score 7):

I was able to get this work. I added the following to my custom CSS:

```
.wpcf7-form textarea{ 
    width: 100% !important;
    height:50px;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Add it after Placeholder attribute.

```
[textarea* message id:message class:form-control 40x7 placeholder "Message"]
```

Comment: That would be before the placeholder.

Answer (score 1):

First create a form for your  [article](https://dracwoundhelps.blogspot.com/2021/11/contact-form-7-textarea-rows.html) and use this syntax

[textarea* your-message 40x7]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

To add cols and rows, use x e.g. You need cols=80 and rows=5, it will be 80x5
It must be placed after the name of the control.

```
[textarea* your-message id:your-message 80x5]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try by adding additional css:

```
.master-cf7-0 .wpcf7 textarea{height:150px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in way to reduce the rows in a textarea in [Contact Form](https://bdasvm.com/contact-us/) 7 based on screen size. However, you can use CSS to achieve this.

Option 1: Using CSS media queries

Add the following CSS to your theme's stylesheet:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .wpcf7-form-control-textarea textarea {
    height: 100px;
  }
}
```

This will reduce the height of the textarea to 100px on screens that are 767px wide or less. You can adjust the height to whatever value you like.

Option 2: Using a custom JavaScript solution

You can also use a custom JavaScript solution to reduce the rows in the textarea based on screen size. Here is a simple example:

JavaScript

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var screenSize = jQuery(window).width();

  if (screenSize <= 767) {
    jQuery('.wpcf7-form-control-textarea textarea').attr('rows', 3);
  }
});
```